# how to delete failed install of ubuntu 12.10

Tags: installation, uninstall

I tried Ubuntu 12.10 on an 2004 desktop computer and unity won't run on it. I installed along side XP. Now I need to remove 12.10 and find a compatible linux destro which will work. Need to say that I am inexperienced in linux? Thanks for any help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would not bother deleting it right now. The next time you will install a distro, simply install it over your Ubuntu 12.10 install, on the same partition. The installation process itself will erase your Ubuntu 12.10, and replace it with your new distro.

Otherwise, you can use a program like GParted to format the partition that Ubuntu 12.10 is currently installed on, this would delete it.

Comment: also good answer, makes sense to leave it since it will be reused. Thank a million.

Answer (score 0):

Here are the steps you need to take:

1. Boot into your Live CD for Ubuntu
2. Start a Terminal session with <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>T</kbd>
3. Type `gksudo gparted` and hit <kbd>Enter</kbd>
4. Delete your Ubuntu partitions (you should have two, the main partition and swap). If you are unsure of which partition is your main Ubuntu partition, type `sudo df` in a Terminal session and hit <kbd>Enter</kbd>. It will be the filesystem mounted on "/".
5. Expand your Windows partition (it should now be the biggest partition) onto the free space by right clicking it and selecting Resize/Move
6. Reboot into a Windows CD
7. Choose Repair
8. Choose Command Prompt
9. Type `bootrec /fixmbr` and hit <kbd>Enter</kbd>
10. Type `bootrec /fiboot` and hit <kbd>Enter</kbd>
11. Reboot. Your computer should now boot into Windows XP.
12. Profit!

If you want a full guide on how uninstall Ubuntu, see [this website](http://www.makeuseof.com/tag/how-to-safely-uninstall-ubuntu-in-windows-dual-boot-environment/).

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend getting either Lubuntu or Xubuntu for your linux distro to replace the current Ubuntu partition. But oftentimes the GUI install does not work (on anything older than about 2006, just forget about graphical installs, and I have a lot of experience trying to load Ubuntu on a P3 computer, AMD k6-2, and a AMD XP).

I would highly recommend going [here](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Lubuntu/Alternate_ISO) and downloading the Lubuntu Alternate ISO. That makes it so you can install from the text-based system, and I was successful in installing Xubuntu 7.10 on an ancient AMD K6-2 with 96 megs of RAM. These alternate install ISOs really work and though they may be slower, it will get you through.

Good luck!

Comment: just saw this answer, and happy to say; I did download and install lubuntu 13.04 graphically, and it is fine. Installed right over the ubuntu!